# My array randomizer function prints the same array

Tags: c, windows

I'm a student learning C
I am trying to write a random string generator for my program, everything runs fine and when I execute the program it prints a random string of letters and numbers but when executed again it prints the same string again.

Code Below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int max=5;
char *randstring(size_t);

main()
{

     char *test;

    test=randstring(max);
    printf("%s",test);
    free(test);
}


char *randstring(size_t length) {

    static char charset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    char *randomString = NULL;

    if (length)
        {
            randomString=malloc(sizeof(char)*(length +1));


        if (randomString)
            {
            for (int n = 0;n<length;n++)
                {
                int key = rand()%(36-1);
                randomString[n] = charset[key];
            }
        }
    }

    return (char *)randomString;
}
```

any help, suggestions, or comments are appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the random number generator:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void main() 
{
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));

    //...Code here
}
```

Comment: Sorry if that was an obvious answer, that fixes my issue. Thank you!